# Swift: Fetch JSON data and update locally

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

In my project, I need to fetch JSON data from the web. At the same time, I will to convert it to `String` and store it on my Core Data.

Assuming I'm fetching this JSON data from the web.

[image]

I only require help to get the data from JSON and convert to `String Array`. Sorry I'm very new to Swift2, and I only know how to code till here.

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)!
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, tested on my machine with a local web service

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/iOSServer/ios/helloworld/getJSONArray")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET" // change it to post if you want

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let data = data{
                do{
                    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                    let resultArray = resultJSON as? NSArray
                    for jsonObjectString in resultArray!{
                        let platform = jsonObjectString["platform"]!
                        let favorite = jsonObjectString["favorite"]!
                        let language = jsonObjectString["language"]!
                        print("platform = \(platform!)")
                        print("favorite = \(favorite!)")
                        print("language = \(language!)")
                    }

                }catch _{
                    print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
                }

            }
            if let response = response {
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }



        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

as you see, inside the `for` loop, i am printing the values that comes form the server, you can do whatever you want with them.

I supposed the JSON keys are: `platform`, `favorite`, and `language` 
You can change them. (please take care of capital and small letters)

Comment: Hi, while I'm still working on the same project, I notice that during debug it exit the program after  `let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in`, where it executes `task.resume()` without going through the `If` statements.

Because of this issue, I failed to extract and display on my UITableView.

Comment: @JoeLeong please create a new question , describe the new problem and send me the link

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. The link as provided.

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666365/fetching-data-from-json-and-display-on-uitableview

Comment: @WilliamKinann I used ur exact method to fetch JSON data and store in my string. I've also included a download link of my project file.

Answer (score 0):

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "url")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        //do something with error
        return
    }

    do {
        if let data = data, jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {

            for object in jsonData {
                var object = Object()
                if let platform = object["platform"] as? String {
                    object.platform = platform
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        //Handle error
    }
})
task.resume()
```